# How to interpret UL listing for NM Clamps stating diameter?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Most NM electrical clamps specifically list the wire combinations they allow, but others such as halex 90515 simply list a bundle diameter range (.835"-1.520")

Does that mean that I can use as many wires as I like provided they sum to within that range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not interpret the catalog page that way.

> APPLICATION: Used to connect non-metallic sheathed cable to a steel outlet box or othermetal enclosure. Dry location.
>
> Fits NM cable, flex cords, multi-flex cords; fitting range .835 - 1.520” diameter or SE cable 2 conductor 4/0

That connector is made for a single cable.  There are small connectors that can be used to secure one or two 14-2 or 12-2 cables, and some specialty connectors that are made for more small cables, but these larger clamps are for a single large cable.

Comment: You think it's made to support a single 1.5" NM cable?

Comment: Yes.  These connectors are very very common and have been around forever.  If it was code compliant to stuff a bundle of NM cables in a connector like this it would be *very* popular and people wouldn't bother with those single cable connectors, but that's not the case.